# How do I append span to span present in html using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
  <h2 class="cs-text">Word Set 
    <span id="words"> 
    </span>
  </h2>
```

in js code:

```
            var spanWordSet = $("#words");
            var li_element = "<span class='char" + word[0] + "'>" + word[0] + "</span>";
            spanWordSet.appendTo(li_element);
```

But I'm not able to append any span tag to the span id=words. 
The idea is to append a bunch of letters as span tag to the span id="words" and then remove them as a whole after a while. Any help?

Comment: you mistake `appendTo` with `append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spanWordSet.appendTo(li_element);
```

should be

```
$(li_element).appendTo(spanWordSet);
```

You have to use the jQuery selector, `$()`.

---

```js
var spanWordSet = $("#words");
var word = ['1'];
var li_element = "<span class='char" + word[0] + "'>" + word[0] + "</span>";
$(li_element).appendTo(spanWordSet);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="cs-text">Word Set 
    <span id="words"> 
    </span>
  </h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spanWordSet.appendTo(li_element);
```

should be other way round

```
$(li_element).appendTo(spanWordSet);
```

Yet another way of doing is

```
spanWordSet.append(li_element);
```